# Automatic swagger documentation for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, swagger

I want To document my Laravel Project APIs. I have like 100 APIs with too many nested relationships. I have to do it with swagger and I currently using

```
https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger
```

now my problem is if I wanna document my API with swagger, I have to manually set annotation for it which is a lot of annotaion and a lot of work to do now like djago which has a package as below :

```
https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/
```

This package automaticly generates the swagger from the API. Now I want to know how can I do this for my Laravel project to be forced to annotate all my projects with my nested APIs.

Comment: Dont use the API tag. Use something which describes your problem better.

Comment: You can checkout https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator It isn't Swagger though

Comment: @OluwafemiSule  unfortunately i need swagger for it is there any package to do it in swagger ???